# jQuery - how to pass in options to a function that creates a datatable from a JSON object

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following that creates a datatable from a JSON object

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.create_datatable_from_json = function(json_object) {
        var table = this.DataTable({
           data: json_object,
           columns: Object.keys(json_object[0]).map(function(item) {
             return { data: item, title: item }
           })
        }) 
      return table;
   }; 
})( jQuery );
```

My question is how would I use another parameter to the function to set the options of the datatable, keeping the first two options (data and columns) alone?

For instance, if I wanted to do:

```
"scrollX": true,
"scrollY": 500,
"paging": false
```

I would call something like:

```
options = {"scrollX": true,"scrollY": 500,"paging": false}
$('#test').create_datatable_from_json(json_object,options);
```

How would I then use `options`

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to first create an object with all data you want to pass to DataTable, then iterate over options to add their keys to your data object :

```js
$.fn.create_datatable_from_json = function(json_object,options) {
    var data={
       data: json_object,
       columns: Object.keys(json_object[0]).map(function(item) {
         return { data: item, title: item }
       })   
    };
    for(x in options)
        data[x]=options[x];
    var table = this.DataTable(data);
    return table;
};
```

It even lets you overwrite columns if you need to.